# bracket notation + javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, brackets, notation

This is my object :

```
Customer{"id": "0001", "name": "ivan" , "country" {"city" : "Peru"}}
```

So: Whats the correct form to use brakets?
the context is in a jquery each:

$. each (datos, function (index, data) {
}

```
1° data["country"["city"]]   >> the result should be "Peru"
2° data["country"]["city"]   >> the result should be "Peru"
```

or whats is the form correct?

Comment: None of this is really valid ?

Comment: Note : `Object == {} && Array == []`. Use a proper syntax.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. Brackets `[]` are used to retrieve a value from an array or object at a particular *index*. The index is the value within the brackets.

Comment: Also, anything like this can never exist: Customer[id: "0001"; name: "ivan" ; country [city : "Peru"]]

Comment: I edit my post, I feel I have been confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you are saying that your object is :

```
Customer  = {
   id: "0001",
   name: "ivan",
   country: {
      city : "Peru"
   }
}
```

In this case your syntax would be either

```
Customer.country.city
```

or

```
Customer["country"]["city"]
```

or any mix of this two

Note also that `Customer[country[something]]` can also be valid syntax, but doesnt seem to be in your case

```
Customer  = {
   id: "0001",
   name: "ivan",
   country: {
      city : "Peru"
   }
}


country = {
   key: 'country'
}

Customer[country['key']]['city']
```

would also return you city `Peru`

Comment: Tnx for answer and correct me. I tried that way but something is wrong, I get null Customer["country"]["city"]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an JavaScript object:

```
Customer[id: "0001"; name: "ivan" ; country [city : "Peru"]]
```

This is an object in JavaScript object:

```
var customer = {
   id: "0001",
   name: "ivan",
   country: {
      finland: {
         city: "Helsinki"
      }
   }
};
```

You would use it with this:

```
console.log(customer.country.finland.city);
```

or this:

```
console.log(customer['country']['finland']['city']);
```

or with mixing....

```
console.log(customer['country'].finland.city);
```

..and yes took a freedom of adding actual country, not just city but I guess this post demonstrates the point, you can either retrieve values with dot notation `customer.country.finland` or apostrophes `customer['country']['finland']` .. However, if you are using numbers as JavaScript object key like this:

```
var customer = {
  1: "Mauno"
};
```

You can retrieve it only using apostrophes as: `customer['1']` trying to use it like `customer.1` will result in a JavaScript error.

Comment: np. glad that you got it solved. Hopefully my post still helps future readers.